# How can we use private chain token in public chain?

Tags: tokens, private-blockchain

I'm software engineer in japan.

now, I'm trying to create a dapp by using private chain like kaleid, then will create token in private chain.

In the future, I'd like our token to be listed to virtual currency exchange.

how can we do that?
there might be several ways for that.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt any exchange accepts private blockchain's coins and/or tokens. In the end it's of course up to the exhchange, but there are at least the following problems:

1) As you control the blockchain you can just take it down when you want to. What should happen to people who have bought your coin/token outside the blockchain?

2) You are able to manipulate the blockchain. Why would someone buy assets which can be manipulated (even removed) at will?

3) You control access to the blockchain. What if you some day decide to block the exchange's access? Furthermore, how are private individuals supposed to connect to the blockchain to check their coins/tokens by themselves?

The topic of your question refers to a slightly different issue so I'll address that one here as well: you can't use assets in blockchain A inside blockchain B without some sort of a bridge. Typically such bridges are centralized and difficult to maintain. So mostly the answer is no, you can't.